# Locking many resources without wait & hold in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I ran into the problem of having to lock 2 or more resources, which led to a Deadlock when using ReentrantReadWriteLocks, even after having the same locking order everywhere*.
I implemented a method that takes Lock Objects, locks them all or rollsback and preempts the current thread:

```
/**
 * Helper Interface for an AutoClosable lock.
 */
public interface ResourceLock extends AutoCloseable {

    /**
     * Unlocking doesn't throw any checked exception.
     */
    @Override
    void close();
}
```

```
public static ResourceLock lockAll(Lock... locks) {
    List<Lock> successful = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean acquired = false;

    for (final Lock lock : locks) {
        acquired = false;
        try {
            acquired = lock.tryLock(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (acquired) {
            successful.add(lock);
        } else {
        break;
        }
    }

    if (!acquired) {
        for (Lock lock1 : successful) {
            lock1.unlock();
        }
        // Preempt the thread and try again
        Thread.yield();
        return lockAll(locks);
    }

    return  () -> {
      for (final Lock lock : locks) {
        lock.unlock();
      }
    };
  }
```

Example usage:

```
try (ResourceLock ignored = lockAll(currentNode.getLock().writeLock(), newNode.getLock().readLock())) {
          currentNode.updateCounts(newNode);
}
```

Not too nice to read.

Here are my questions:
 - How does one properly preempt Threads in Java?
 - Is the use of Thread.yield() okay or would Thread.sleep(1) be more appropriate?
 - Is there something more elegant than this? e.g. did I oversee a best practice to do this or sth. in util.concurrency?

*The code shall implement a multi-threaded version of conceptual clustering/Cobweb (Fisher, 1987) recursively. The locking order is always parent, currently visited node, new node. But as the threads may be in different levels of the tree at the same time there is at some point an overlap between child in a higher and parent in a lower tree level that leads to the deadlock.

Comment: unclear, `extends AutoCloseable` why and where it is used. I also have many questions. what is this code supposed to do. what are you locking ?

Comment: I'm locking multiple nodes in a tree, e.g. a parent node and one child at a time. The Autocloseable is in order to have auto closing locks (just for convenience).

Comment: Probably better to debug "even after having the same locking order everywhere" - because that was probably not the case. Did you check which threads held which locks at the point that you had a deadlock?

Comment: If your code worked, it wouldn’t be different to a plain `for(Lock lock: locks) lock.lock();`, but all this additional unnecessary complexity bears a lot of potential for errors. I can’t spot one immediately, but that doesn’t say anything. Why don’t you drop that code and use the straight-forward loop? But note that this lock-in-order pattern works safely for an reentrant lock, it doesn’t work the same way when you mix read and write locks.

Comment: "Preempt" is the wrong word. Preemption is involuntary. It's something that the operating system does to your threads. It's beyond the control of your program.  What your program does at the point of your "Preempt the thread..." comment is, it is _yielding_ to other threads.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, works fine with ReentrantLocks instead of ReentrantReadWriteLocks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the use of Thread.yield() okay? or would Thread.sleep(1) be more appropriate?

You should be aware that `Thread.yield()` is not guaranteed to do anything at all. It's an anachronism from a time when somebody imagined that Java programs might possibly run in a *[cooperative multitasking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_multitasking)* environment.  Cooperative multitasking still exists, but you won't often find it on systems that are powerful enough to host a JVM.

The `sleep(1)` call *is* guaranteed to yield, but it will impact the program's performance---a millisecond is a long time these days. Whether or not the impact is too great is a question that only you can answer.

I have seen `sleep(0)` in Java code, but I don't know whether that is required to behave any differently from `yield()`.

---

> Is there something more elegant than this?

Maybe not more elegant, but you can avoid the overhead of locking and unlocking multiple OS mutexes (i.e., `Lock` objects) by keeping a global `Set` of tree nodes that are "locked," and using a single, global `Lock` object to control access to the `Set`.